# @JsonIgnore field in frontend UI and include it in Jsonb json serialization to store in Postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, jackson, jax-rs, jsonb

I need a field to be ignored in front end UI, whereas the same field will be calculated in backend and needs to get stored in Postgres DB as a Jsonb object. Other than transforming the value object into a newer one, do we have any feature in Jackon for this use case.

**Test.java**

```
public class Test {

    private Integer score;

    private Date dateValidated = null;

    private Boolean consent = false;

    private Date dateConsented;

    public void setConsent(Boolean consent) {
        this.consent = consent;
        this.dateConsented = consent ? new Date() : null;
    }

}
```

Based on consent, dateConsented will be set and i don't want this to be set while calling my service. I can use @JsonIgnore for this

**Problem**

I will store this Test as json object in postgres (Jsonb). So if i use @JsonIgnore dateConsented will be ignored in DB as well. I don't want that to happen. Any suggestions/solution for this?

Comment: show Your java class. Without code Your idea is not clear (personally for me - totally unclear)

Comment: Can't you just not display the field in the UI? or set it to null before sending in JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a resource class for yourself, and convert this class to it. finally return this resource class to frontend UI.Take a look ConverterFactory from spring.

Comment: I have mentioned this option in my question itself. I have asked this question to check if there are any solution with jackson or any other framework.

Comment: But this is normal design pattern in this case. Because if in some day you decide to now show score field just like date, you can handle this by just changing your resource class. Thanks to this solution, nowhere can affect in your program except your UI.